# Object Duplication/Serialization problem

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm having a bit of a problem with a data serialization method I'm using to copy objects. Here's the method:

```
public static class ObjectDuplicator
        {
            public static T Clone<T>(T source)
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("the Type must be serializable.", "source");
                }

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null)) //dont try to serialize a null object
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                using (stream)
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is this: when I call this method using the code below

```
public void AddJob(Job job)
        {
            if (!Jobs.Contains(job))
            {
                Job newcopy = Utilities.ObjectDuplicator.Clone<Job>(job);

                Jobs.Add(newcopy);
            }
        }
```

it throws this exception:

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'KH.CharacterClasses.Freelancer' to type 'KH.CharacterClasses.Job'

Now, the type of job I'm adding is an inherited class from Job, (Freelancer) and the code for those two classes is below

```
[Serializable]
    public class Job : Ability
    {
        protected JobCommand basecommand1;
        protected JobCommand basecommand2;
        protected JobCommand basecommand3;
        protected JobCommand basecommand4;
        protected JobCommand command1;
        protected JobCommand command2;
        protected JobCommand command3;
        protected JobCommand command4;
        bool mastered;
        protected FFJob job;
        protected string name;
        int level; 

        public FFJob SetJob
        {
            get
            {
                return job;
            }
        }
        public bool Mastered
        {
            get
            {
                return mastered;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand Command1
        {
            get
            {
                return command1;
            }
            set
            {
                command1 = value;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand DefaultCommand1
        {
            get
            {
                return basecommand1;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand Command2
        {
            get
            {
                return command2;
            }
            set
            {
                command2 = value;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand DefaultCommand2
        {
            get
            {
                return basecommand2;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand Command3
        {
            get
            {
                return command3;
            }
            set
            {
                command3 = value;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand DefaultCommand3
        {
            get
            {
                return basecommand3;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand Command4
        {
            get
            {
                return command4;
            }
            set
            {
                command4 = value;
            }
        }

        public JobCommand DefaultCommand4
        {
            get
            {
                return basecommand4;
            }
        }

        public Job(string name, string description, int jobID)
            : base(name, description, jobID, -1, -1, null, null, -1, -1)
        {
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Job job1, Job job2)
        {
            if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(job1, job2))
                return true;
            if (((object)job1 == null) || ((object)job2 == null))
                return false;
            return (job1.Name == job2.Name && job1.UID == job2.UID);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Job job1, Job job2)
        {
            return !(job1 == job2);
        }


       // public abstract void CharacterModifier(BaseCharacter character);

       // public abstract void CharacterDemodifier(BaseCharacter character);
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Freelancer : Job
    {
        public Freelancer()
            : base("Freelancer", "A character not specializing in any class. Can combine the power of all mastered Jobs.", Globals.JobID.ID)
        {
            basecommand1 = JobCommand.Attack;
            basecommand2 = JobCommand.Free;
            basecommand3 = JobCommand.Free;
            basecommand4 = JobCommand.Items;
            command1 = basecommand1;
            command2 = basecommand2;
            command3 = basecommand3;
            command4 = basecommand4;
            job = FFJob.Freelancer;
        }
    }
```

I'm a bit stumped here because I know the ObjectDuplicator method does work. In fact, this code HAS worked before, but that was on a different computer, and I haven't looked at it in awhile. I'm a little stumped as to why the casting fails here. If someone could help me out with whats wrong thatd be great. If you need more details, just say what you need. I asked this question yesterday, but didn't get a workable answer.

Thanks

Comment: That code is working just fine for me.

Comment: really? What versrion of .Net are you using? Target CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution here:

[Casting Error when using serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590877/casting-error-when-using-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

with

```
var result = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
for (Type now = result.GetType(); now != null; now = now.BaseType)
    MessageBox.Show(now.FullName);
return result as T;
```

What does `Clone<T>` return? Do you see `KH.CharacterClasses.Job` in a list of base types? Seems like it's not the base type for `Freelancer`.

Comment: Yep that method printed out

KH.CharacterClasses.Freelancer
KH.CharacterClasses.Job
KH.CharacterClasses.Ability
KH.StatusEffects.StatusEffect
System.Object

They're definitely the same base class, as I have no trouble casting it outside of the ObjectDuplicator method

Comment: Is ObjectDuplicator in a separate assembly?

Comment: My setup: .NET 4.0, x86. Removed FFJob job; and replaced JobCommand with String - works well. Try removing fields one by one. Does this work? [Serializable]class A {} [Serializable]class B : A {} static void Act() { ObjectDuplicator.Clone<A>(new B()); }

Comment: okay well this is strange, when i do this:

[Serializable]
        public class A
        {
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class B : A
        {
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            A a = ObjectDuplicator.Clone<A>(new B());
        }

now it's telling me: "Unable to load type KH.Utilities+B required for deserialization."

Comment: Really strange. Do you use obfuscator for that assembly? Or try disabling any optimization

Comment: nope, just a standard compile. And I'm running this in debug so there no optimization anyways. Thanks for help so far though

Answer (score 0):

I would never place a return statement into a using clause! Do this instead:

```
object tClone = null;
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
 formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 tClone = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
return (T)tClone;
```

If the exception is still thrown, then your types are indeed incompatible...

Comment: Same exception... but I KNOW they're compatible. I can cast them just fine outside of this serialization method, and Freelancer's base class is Job